# While GSConnect works fine at home, it doesn't work at my workplace

Tags: kde-connect

At home, GSConnect connects my android phone with my laptop with no problems. But at my workplace, it doesn't work. In my android application (KDE Connect), when tapping my laptop under "remembered devices", it just says:

> This paired device is not reachable. Make sure it is connected to your
> same network.

But both my devices are connected to the same network (the wi-fi network of my employer).
Is there anything I can try to do to make it work?

**An attempt to clarify my question:**
Is it possible that GSConnect works on some networks only? (Because it does work on my home network but it does not work on the network at my workplace.) How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that they are connected to the same network.

Then, find the IP address of your office computer with the command `ip address`. Then, manually add this IP address to the KDE Connect app on your mobile phone.

Then, the computer should show up in the phone.

It may so happen that the network dynamically assigns an IP address each time you connect to the internet, so you will have to repeat the process after restarting the computer.

Comment: Or it may be the case that [AP isolation](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/2089/), NATting, Firewalling or Captive Portal's multiple sub-netting(separate guest network) is enabled.

Comment: At work, I use the same laptop (and phone) as home. So the only difference is in the network. And both of them are connected to the same network. I will try the IP address "trick" later to see if it helps.

Comment: @hello I regularly encounter this issue. In my workplace, the phone cannot find my laptop unless I add the IP address manually. Not a problem at home (probably because the home computer's IP address does not keep changing).